# What blogs or RSS sites do you subscribe to, to keep up with current technology?

Tags: untagged

I am more of a developer than an IT technician.

So I am not to sure where to look to keep up with current technologies.
I only follow a couple of technology sites such as

- [Paul Thurrott's SuperSite for Windows](http://www.winsupersite.com/)
- [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/) and [Engadget](http://www.engadget.com/) for Gadgets/Tools/Etc

What other sites would you recommend for new technologies?
I am interested in not only Microsoft technologies but also *NIX side of things, as well.

Answer (score 7):

[Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) - Tech news without the politics.

Answer (score 2):

[Slashdot](http://slashdot.org)'s the obvious pick.

[Linux Weekly News](http://lwn.net) is another good item for Linux.

My favorite though is [Google Tech Talks](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/googletechtalks/uploads)

I'd be remiss not to mention open source Planets for projects like [Debian](http://planet.debian.org) or [Ubuntu](http://planet.ubuntu.com)

Comment: I haven't checked out SlashDot for about 5 years, it slipped my mind ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Lifehacker](http://www.lifehacker.com) tends to have articles about all kinds of technology-related things that are useful in every day life.

They cover software, provide tips for using and customizing your technology, and information about new software and hardware releases.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what was mentioned above, for information on newer hardware I occasionally visit:

- [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/)
- [[H]ard|OCP](http://www.hardocp.com/)
- [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[JCXP](http://www.jcxp.net) always seems to have the scoop on Windows developments.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with [jldugger](https://serverfault.com/questions/2880/what-blogs-or-rss-sites-do-you-subscribe-to-to-keep-up-with-current-technology/2883#2883), specially about Google Tech Talks, really great stuff there.

I also follow [Dave Jones blog](http://www.codemonkey.org.uk/). He's a kernel developer for the Fedora project, and every now and then he posts something cool.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in Microsoft products, I would recommend you check out MSDN's [Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) video blog.  There is a lot of great content there on up-and-coming products and features a lot of influentials within the company.

Answer (score 0):

I usually subscribe to the blogs of the IT & Geeks I follow at [twitter.com](http://twitter.com/MarlonRibunal)

Comment: Who are some of the people in IT field I should be subscribing to ?